# How well can rectangles approximate geometric shapes?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, optimization

Let $f$ be a polynomial with domain $\mathbb{R}^d$. Define the set $A := \{ x  \;|\; f(x) = 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. I assume this set is bounded (in the easiest case it might be the boundary of a ball).

Given an integer $m \in \mathbb{N}$, how would we identify the optimal choice of $m$ **axis-aligned** affine hyperplanes $Q_1, ..., Q_m$ approximating $A$ by minimizing the distance of any point in $A$ to the hyperplanes? That is, we aim to minimize...

$$\max_{x \in A} \min_{y \in Q} \|x-y\|^2$$

where $Q := \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} Q_i$

Are there algorithms to perform this task and do we have results on how good the approximation is depending on $m$ or the degree of the polynomial $f$?

It is clear that for $m$ sufficiently large we can always approximate any set $A$ up to some small $\epsilon$ and likewise, that if $m$ is small and $\deg(f)$ is large, we can't hope for any reasonable approximation.

Comment: I suppose you mean to require that your hyperplanes have the same dimension as the target surface (or just dimension $d-1$) to avoid the solution of enclosing the whole object in one big box.

Comment: The problem reminds me of data clustering in the sense that you're trying to partition $A$ so as to allocate its points to different planes. An iterative algorithm analogous to [expectation maximization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) might work.

Comment: That is, start with a guess for how to partition A and then in alternation: find the best approximating plane for each class, and re-partition $A$ according to which plane is actually closest to each point.